# jQuery bind to a variable event

Tags: jquery, variables

I'd like to use a variable to store which event i'm going to bind to.

Something like:

```
var the_event = 'mouseover';
$().bind(the_event, function(){
    console.log('hi there!');
});
```

I could achieve the same thing with `if`s, but i'd rather use a better way, might one exist!

What i want to do, with `if`s:

```
var the_event = 'mouseover';

var the_function = function(){
    console.log('hi there!');
}

if(the_event == 'mouseover'){
    $().bind('mouseover', the_function);
} else if(the_event == 'click'){
    $().bind('click', the_function);
}
```

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

What i'm actually tring to do is:

```
var events = {
    one: 'mouseover',
    two: 'mouseout'
};

$().bind({
    events.one: function(){
        console.log('1');
    },
    events.two: function(){
        console.log('2');
    },
);
```

Comment: did you try your first example?

Comment: you're first example is exactly correct.  you've answered you're own question.  I highly recommend actually putting a selector into jQuery's $() call though.

Comment: When you say "I could achieve the same thing", what are you talking about? The same thing as what? Your first example should work perfectly fine.

Comment: i did, at least with another syntax, because i'm binding multiple events at once: `$().bind({ my_events.one: the_function, my_events.two: the_function });`

Comment: well ok, i'll modify the example so that it matches exactly my case, but i guess the answer will be similar to the last example x)

Comment: I've updated my answer to address what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example would work fine if there were something in the `$()` at the beginning. [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) accepts a string, it doesn't care whether the string comes from a literal or from a variable.

This:

```
$("some_selector").bind("click", function(event) {
    // ...
});
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
var event_name = "click";
$("some_selector").bind(event_name, function(event) {
    // ...
});
```

...other than the existence of the `event_name` variable, of course. [Gratuitous live example](http://jsbin.com/ecatek)

---

If you want to do multiple events, you can do that too, but you have to create the object you're passing to `bind` in advance:

```
var events = {};
var eventName1 = "click";
var eventName2 = "dblclick";
events[eventName1] = function(event) { /* ... */ };
events[eventName2] = function(event) { /* ... */ };
$("some_selector").bind(events);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ecatek/2)

You can't do it directly in the literal because the thing to the left of the `:` in an object literal **must** be a literal or a literal string, it cannot be the result of an expression (and so cannot be a variable reference), e.g., this will *not* work:

```
var eventName1 = "click";
var eventName2 = "dblclick";
$("some_selector").bind({
    eventName1: function() { /* ... */ }, // <== Wrong, doesn't use variable, uses "eventName1"
    eventName2: function() { /* ... */ }  // <== Wrong (same reason)
});
```

So applying that to the code example you just added to the question, you'd get:

```
var events = {
    one: 'mouseover',
    two: 'mouseout'
};

var bindEvents = {};
bindEvents[events.one] = function(){
    console.log('1');
};
bindEvents[events.two] = function(){
    console.log('2');
};
$(/* You need something here */).bind(bindEvents);
```

Comment: i'm sorry for the misleading example, i just edited the question

Comment: alright, that seems great, and logical too :) let me find time to test this and i'll come back to you!

Comment: it's working awesome, i just lacked the openmind to build the object to use with `.bind()`, although i knew why it couldnt work the way i tried :) thanks!

Comment: how to achive this to here; var EVENT = 'hover';                                                                                                                                       $("#stk").bind(EVENT,function(e) {
   st.drawbox(e);
},function(e) {
   st.clearbox(e);
});

Comment: Hello, old question! Update to TJ's answer: What I was trying to do at the time, that is using computed property names in object literals, is now [part of the ES6 spec](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object-initializer). This would work in an environment that implements the new syntax: `var o = { ["prop" + "erty"]: "val" }`

Comment: @Pioul: I'd missed that! Cool!

Answer (score 0):

`bind()` takes the name of the event as a string as the first argument, so:

```
$("#elem").bind(the_event, function(){
    console.log('hi there!');
});
```

will work. See here:
http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: i'm sorry for the misleading example, i just edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You can always do that what you are trying to do since the first argument of `bind` method is a string event name. Alternatively you can also use and json map to pass multiple event handlers in the `bind` method. Take  a look at here [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

```
$('#foo').bind({
  click: function() {
    // do something on click
  },
  mouseenter: function() {
    // do something on mouseenter
  }
});
```

Comment: i'm sorry for the misleading example, i just edited the question